How to `tag_configure` for changing only font `weight`?
I have a text widget and defined two tags for two different font faces:
text1.tag_configure("var", font=textfont)
text1.tag_configure("mon", font=fixedfont)

Now, I want to define one more tag to make either the mono spaced (fixedfont) or variable spaced (textfont) font bold. I defined something like this:
text1.tag_configure("bld", font='-weight bold')

However, this does not work:
text1.insert(END, "mono typed bolded text", "mon bld")

And changes the font face to something probably default.
Obviously, I need something like:
text1.tag_configure("bld", weight="bold")

Which is not accepted and gives _unknown option "-weight" error.
Assuming that I am using and have configured tags for dozens of different fonts, how can I configure a single tag to change just the weight of a font (any font)?

I don't think the text widget allows you to combine multiple tags together. You may have to create your own algorithm to "solve" this problem. See similar problem here
